# inserting php text validation to database

Tags: php

hi guys i need your help Im new in this field 
i have created a form and i want to validate it using php then after validation
i want to insert it in my database but the validation didnt work please help me :(

```
<?php

  $fname = "";
  $fnameErr = "";
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
  {
     if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $fnameErr = "Firsname required"; 
     }else{
        $fname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
         $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
     }
  }

  function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
   }

   mysql_connect('localhost','root','G0cl');
   mysql_select_db('db') or die ('Unable to connect to database');
   $insert_query = "INSERT into tbl values('$fname')" ;
   $record_insert = mysql_query($insert_query);
?>

<?php
  include "process.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>  
     <head>
        <title>practice</title>
     </head>  
     <body>
        <h2>Absolute classes registration</h2>
        <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>">
           <input type = "text" name = "firstname" placeholder=" Firsname ">
           <span class = "error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
           <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
        </form>
     </body>
  </html>
```

[image: my database is like this]

Comment: could you please be more verbose? What you have, what you get, what you tested

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions, an alternative could be Pdo or Mysqli with prepared statements to help avoid SQL injection.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `test_input` function?

Comment: What if my first name is `D'Arcy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reads:

```
If POST:
  Do validation.

Do database insert.

Display form (with errors/feedback).
```

In other words it doesn't matter if validation fails or not.

You want logic along the lines of:

```
If POST
  Do validation

If no validation errors:
  Do database insert.
  If insert success:
      Redirect.

Display form (with errors/feedback).
```

Example here:

```
<?php

$errors = [];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
{
  $firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? trim($_POST['firstname']) : null;

  if (empty($firstname)) {
    $errors['firstname'] = "Firstname required."; 
  }
  elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $firstname)) {
    $errors['firstname'] = "Only letters and white space allowed."; 
  }
  // etc.
  if(! count($errors)) {
    echo 'Passed validation, do database insert and then redirect here.';      
  }    
}

$show_error = function($key) use ($errors) {
  if(isset($errors[$key])) {    
    return  '<span class = "error">*' . $errors[$key] . '</span>';
  }
};

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
      <title>Form</title>
    </head>  
    <body>

      <h2>Absolute beginners</h2>

      <form method = "POST" action = "">

          <input type = "text" name = "firstname" placeholder="e.g. Joe.">
          <?= $show_error('firstname'); ?>

          <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"> 

      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php

  $fname = "";
  $fnameErr = "";

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
  {
     if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $fnameErr = "Firsname required"; 
     }else{
        $fname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
         $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }
      else{
       mysql_connect('localhost','root','G0cl');
       mysql_select_db('db') or die ('Unable to connect to database');

       $insert_query = "INSERT into tbl values('$fname')" ;
       $record_insert = mysql_query($insert_query);
}
     }
  }
      function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
     }


  ?>

  <?php
  include "process.php";
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>  
     <head>
        <title>practice</title>
     </head>  
     <body>

        <h2>Absolute classes registration</h2>

        <form method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>">

           <input type = "text" name = "firstname" placeholder=" Firsname ">
           <span class = "error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>

           <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"> 

        </form>
     </body>
  </html>
```

You need to include your insert query code after the preg_match. If preg_match false then then the firstname can be inserted to database table.